# Подсчет времени работы программы

Tags: c, windows, winapi, время

Каким образом можно подсчитать время работы программ, например, пузырьковой сортировки?

Comment: Например, см. [`clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock). В C++ всякие таймеры проработаны получше, конечно... но можно воспользоваться API операционной системы.

Comment: @Harry.а если не линукс , а виндоус ?

Comment: А `clock` не зависит от операционка :) А в Windows есть такая замечательная парочка QueryPerformanceCounter - QueryPerformanceFrequency...

Comment: @Harry,вижу только их использование на си++, но не на си

Comment: А в чем разница-то?...

Comment: @Harry, можно ,пожалуйста,привести пример того, как с помощью этого инструмента можно было бы посчитать время работы функции , вызываемой из главной программы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот вам пример на чистом C, примерно так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

long long getFreq()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER f;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&f);
    return f.QuadPart;
}

long long muTime()
{
    static long long freq = 0;
    if (freq == 0) freq = getFreq();
    LARGE_INTEGER t;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t);
    return (t.QuadPart * 1000000L)/freq;
}


int main()
{
    long long start = muTime();

    Sleep(1000);

    long long stop = muTime();

    printf("%lld mks\n",stop-start);

}
```

Измерение времени в микросекундах.

Только учтите, что на измерения могут влиять куча разных факторов, так что лучше проводить много замеров, да и саму функцию, скажем, в цикле вызывать много раз, а потом суммарное время делить на число итераций - ну, чтоб случайные факторы устранить...

Comment: `QueryPerformanceCounter()` — это всё же WINAPI, а не чистый C...

Comment: А мы и обсуждали это в комментариях к вопросу - ТС спросил о Windows, я ответил, он попросил привести пример... Посмотрите сами, как развивалось обсуждение...

Comment: да я видел, но «чистым C» от этого он не становится ;)

Comment: я вообще намекал на то чтобы в ответе слова про «чистый С» подправить ж)